# AWS DynamoDB many to many schema design clarification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My access pattern/query would be: Get Name and Email of all friends by user (example USER#1).

I have added GSI to invert PK and SK which will allow me to query using SK.

Sample data is below in table,

```
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
|   PK   |    SK    | Name |     Email     |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
| USER#1 | USER#1   | Bob  | bob@email.com |
| USER#2 | USER#2   | Rob  | rob@email.com |
| USER#3 | USER#3   | Tom  | tom@email.com |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 |      |               |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#3 |      |               |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
```

My question is it possible to get friends of USER#1 in single query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, if you want to do that in a single query, you need to store them pre-joined in DynamoDB. In other words, for example, store the fourth row as something like this. `| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 | Rob  | rob@email.com |`. This is also known as "denormalization".

Comment: @jellycsc - ahh thank you, was thinking about this as last option, only problem with that is to update pre-joined data each time when any user update name or email etc.

Comment: An alternative could be storing the data in the format as described in the question. Then use [`BatchGetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) to bulk retrieve them.

Comment: Interesting, If you request more than 100 items, BatchGetItem returns a ValidationException with the message "Too many items requested for the BatchGetItem call.". Sure a user can have more than 100 friends.

Comment: You can do a for loop of course :/ This is kind of the trade-off you get when using ddb.

Comment: yes, will try to explore any other cheap option. Otherwise plan B is as you suggested. Thank you v much.

Comment: np, please consider accepting my answer below. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Denormalization

Store the data in the following format:

```
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
|   PK   |    SK    | Name |     Email     |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
| USER#1 | USER#1   | Bob  | bob@email.com |
| USER#2 | USER#2   | Rob  | rob@email.com |
| USER#3 | USER#3   | Tom  | tom@email.com |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 | Rob  | rob@email.com |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#3 | Tom  | tom@email.com |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
```

- Pro: can query and get user name and email directly
- Con: update becomes expensive

#### Option 2: BatchGetItem

Store the data as it is, aka

```
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
|   PK   |    SK    | Name |     Email     |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
| USER#1 | USER#1   | Bob  | bob@email.com |
| USER#2 | USER#2   | Rob  | rob@email.com |
| USER#3 | USER#3   | Tom  | tom@email.com |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 |      |               |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#3 |      |               |
+--------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Then use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) API to retrieve the name and email for each friend.

- Pro: data is "normalized" (less duplication, less storage)
- Con: you need to do BatchGetItem's in a for loop if you want to retrieve all the friends' details